# ASP.NET SQL Search Engine Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, search

I keep getting this error when trying to use `@itemname` in a SQL search query. The code should search the values in the SQL table and display them here. Thanks.

> Must declare the scalar variable "@itemname".

Code for `search.aspx`:

```
<body>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="searchresults" runat="server"
        ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>'
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [itemname] FROM [reports] WHERE ([itemname] LIKE '%' + @itemname + '%')">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:ListView ID="displayitems" runat="server" DataSourceID="searchresults" DataKeyNames="ID">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <span>
                No items for <asp:Label Text='' runat="server" ID="itemname" />
            </span>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"
                NavigateURL='<%# "Sale.aspx?saleid=" + Eval("ID") %>'>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("itemname") %>' runat="server" ID="ItemNameLabel" /> <br />
            </asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The message means the parameter `itemname` is not declared. Try adding the parameter into the `SqlDataSource`

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ... OnSelecting="ds_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="itemname" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
    </SelectParameters>

    ....
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and then in the code behind set its value:

```
protected void ds_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters[0].Value = "Value";
}
```

There are many options for setting the value using derived classes of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter`, some of these classes do not require code behind, for example `asp:ControlParameter` or `asp:QueryStringParameter`.

Comment: Il give it a go. Although itemname is the name of one of the rows in my SQL database? its that i want to search for, are you sure i should be setting its value?

Comment: i just found [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1115044.aspx?Passing+Parameters+for+SqlDataSource+from+code+behind), the parameter value is set in the code behind there.

Comment: i still cant get this to work correctly, i was following a tutorial that doesnt include touching the code behind file. I cannot work out the problem.

Comment: It is possible to do without code behind, for example  `asp:ControlParameter` binds parameter value to another control, and there are more options, please see the updated answer.

Comment: If you have a search box (`asp:TextBox`) on `search.aspx` page then use `asp:ControlParameter`. If you open page like `search.aspx?keyword=how+to+buy+something` them use `asp:QueryStringParameter`. Both approaches allow to get results without code behind.