# SQL search error ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

keep getting this error when trying to use @itemname in a SQL search query. The code should search the values in the SQL table and display them here. Thanks.

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@itemname".
```

Code for search.aspx

```
<body>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="searchresults" runat="server"
        ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>'
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [itemname] FROM [reports] WHERE ([itemname] LIKE '%' + @itemname + '%')">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:ListView ID="displayitems" runat="server" DataSourceID="searchresults" DataKeyNames="ID">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <span>
                No items for <asp:Label Text='' runat="server" ID="itemname" />
            </span>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"
                NavigateURL='<%# "Sale.aspx?saleid=" + Eval("ID") %>'>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("itemname") %>' runat="server" ID="ItemNameLabel" /> <br />
            </asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</body>
```

Comment: Well....you have the parameter @itemname in your query but you don't have a parameter defined in the code you shared.

Comment: Your select command has a variable for the itemname.  How should itemname be populated?

Comment: itemname is a row in my sql database, i want to be able to search the name of products based on this row. Im not sure how to go about defining the paramater or how it should be populated. Really lost!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET SQL Search Engine Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121598/asp-net-sql-search-engine-error)

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the parameter to the `@itemname`

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="searchresults" runat="server"
        ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>'
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [itemname] FROM [reports] WHERE ([itemname] LIKE '%' + @itemname + '%')">

<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="itemname" Type="String"  />
  </SelectParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and in code behind you can set the value of the parameter

```
searchresults.SelectParameters("itemname").DefaultValue = "some value";
```